# Send notification in android

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app, and would like to send a notification at specific time every day.
this is my code:

```
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(alarm);
    Intent intent = new Intent("WAKE_UP");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);

 time use AlarmManager.set().

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis() , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);

    // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent2, 0);

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(" boghche " + "shake")
            .setContentText("Shake kon :/").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
           .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

But I can not send it in specific time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440251/how-to-repeat-notification-daily-on-specific-time-in-android-through-background/23440985#23440985

Comment: What is the API Level?

Answer (score 0):

> First set the Alarm Manager as below

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlaramReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

> Create an Broadcast Receiver Class "AlaramReceiver" in this raise the
>   notifications when onReceive

```
public class AlaramReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, EVentsPerform.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                .setContentTitle("Alaram Fired")
                .setContentText("Events To be PErformed").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        MID++;

    }

}
```

> In the Manifest you can add the below permissions for this

```
<!-- permission required to use Alarm Manager -->
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

 <!-- Register the Alarm Receiver -->
 <receiver android:name="com.example.alarammanagernotifcation.AlaramReceiver"/>
```

Comment: where should i set the Alarm Manager?

Comment: and what is EVentsPerform class?

Comment: and i have error : can not resolve 'NotificationCompat'

Comment: MID is int data type... when multiple notifications received increment the MID value.. import the ---->import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

Comment: set the Alarm Manager in oncreate function?

Comment: oh..Yes...as your wish

Comment: what should i do in  EVentsPerform class

Comment: i do this,but not happend!!

Comment: Event Perform class for when click on the notification, it calls the Event Perform class

Comment: now when the time was 18:30 ,must show the notification?but it wasnt

Comment: Is the alarm fire..first check..test for every 1 min like that...it's working in my case.....