# Execute alaramManager.setRepeating() on condition

Tags: android, oop, alarmmanager

I have implemented a simple app that shows notification at particular intervals using alaramManager just as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23440985/2649104) .

I have a static `bool shouldNotify` class level variable in main activity.
I need `setRepearing` to execute only if my `shouldNotify`  is true. 
How shall it be done?

EDIT:

One way is by notifying on condition(as specified in the first answer), but that will drain the battery as alaram will always be fired. Is there any better option?

Let me know if its too vague to be asked here. I am new to OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your alarm be repeated as it is. Just put your `if(shouldNotify)` check in `onReceive()` method. Thus you will check, whether to send notification or not.

**EDIT**

I guess, it is not an optimal solution, yes.
As an alternative, if you care about battery life, you can cancel alarm, when `shouldNotify`changes to `false` and start again when it turns to `true`.

Comment: Is this a good practice? Wont this drain the battery if alarm is too frequent which is in my case. Is it possible to put condition on `setRepeating`?