# Daily repeating notifications with deprecated N̶o̶t̶i̶f̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶C̶o̶m̶p̶a̶t̶.̶B̶u̶i̶l̶d̶e̶r̶

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I am searching for the latest code for creating notification because the code I have doesn't work and it says that the code is deprecated.

My code is literally similar to an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440251/how-to-repeat-notification-daily-on-specific-time-in-android-through-background), except that mine looks like this...

[image]

And on my manifest it turns red, idk why;

### [image]

However I also have this code(and it works) but I can't figure a way on how to make it repeat daily on a specified time;

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), i, 0);

    Bitmap bitmapI = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Sample title")
            .setContentText("Sample content")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmapI)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification.flags |=  Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);`
```

If you guys wanted to see my actual code just say and i will edit my question.

Comment: I believe this is a better duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462666/notificationcompat-builder-deprecated-in-android-o

Comment: Add `NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")`

Comment: @LeeArmstrong I have included.

Comment: But what about on my manifest file, do guys have any idea why it turns red?